# *ngFor for a data-range without a data-property in the component

Tags: angular, range, ngfor

Is there an easy way to create option fields of a select box with *ngFor for the last 20 years, e.g. from a value 2016 to value 1996, without having a data property in the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way around creating an array.

AFAIK the size of the array that can be created in the template is limited to 10 or 20 (this limit might also have been removed recently - not sure).

```
*ngFor="let x of [1,2,3...]"
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8168

Use instead something like:

```
*ngFor="let x of years"
```

```
constructor() {
  this.years = []; 
  for(let i = 0; i < 20; ++i) { 
    this.years.push(2000 + i);
  } 
}
```